# Automapper flattened DTO to Parent with Child Collection

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, automapper-6

I have a flattened DTO which I need to map to a Parent with Children relationship.  I'd like to do this via AutoMapper as I'm using it in other places and it works great.  I've seen examples of mapping a Parent and Child but not when the Child is a collection and the source is a flattened DTO.  I've created some classes that I can use for getting the configuration correct.  Below are my sample classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }

    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
public class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
public class ParentChildDTO
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string ParentName { get; set; }
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

I'm performing the mapper initialization on startup.  I'm not getting any errors until I try to perform the mapping.  Below is my mapper initialization code.  I've kept in the commented out line to show the other way that I've tried to accomplish this:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<ParentChildDTO, Child>();
                cfg.CreateMap<ParentChildDTO, Parent>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
                    //.ForMember(dest => dest.Children, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new Child { ChildId = src.ChildId, ChildName = src.ChildName }));               

            });
```

Below is my code that I'm using for trying to perform the mapping configuration:

```
ParentChildDTO parentChildDTO = new ParentChildDTO { ParentId = 1, ParentName = "Parent Name", ChildId = 2, ChildName = "Child Name" };
Parent parent = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<ParentChildDTO, Parent>(parentChildDTO);

List<LienActivity> mapTest = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<BaseActivityUploadDTO>, List<LienActivity>>(request.Activities);
```

I've considered using a Custom Value Resolver, but was hoping to avoid the complexity and extra code if what I'm doing is possible with the correct configuration.

Here's the error that I get with the above code:

> Error mapping types.
>
> Mapping types: ParentChildDTO -> Parent
>
> Type Map configuration: ParentChildDTO -> Parent
>
> Property: Children

Comment: im a little confused how you flatten the relationship into a single dimension when parent has N number of children.  i suppose flattening could use the first child and in reverse could always create a list of children with length one? is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm trying to achieve.  Basically, the scenario is an excel spreadsheet with each row mapping to a DTO.  For an upload, there will only ever be one child in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option where you define custom mapping just for the Children property.

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMap<ParentChildDTO, Parent>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Children, 
         opt => opt.MapFrom(src => new List<Child>() { new Child() { ChildId = src.ChildId, ChildName = src.ChildName } }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is what I tried to use during one iteration but I had the syntax incorrect for the MapFrom.

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are going to use this for based on your comments - the below configuration should do the job (parent properties are resolved by default AutoMapper conventions so no need to explicitly map):

```
        AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ParentChildDTO, Parent>()
                .ConstructUsing(item => new Parent
                {
                    Children = new List<Child>
                    {
                        new Child
                        {
                            ChildId = item.ChildId,
                            ChildName = item.ChildName
                        }
                    }
                });
        });
```

Comment: This solution also worked.  Ultimately, I ended up using the other solution so I marked it as the answer.  Thank you for your response!